# Why am I getting blocked when I call OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) from sys.dm_tran_locks?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dmv, metadata, blocking

I'm working on a query to tell what objects have locks from a given session and I'm running into some blocking issues.

Here is my basic query:

```
SELECT request_session_id AS session_id, 
    request_owner_id AS transaction_id,
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(resource_associated_entity_id, resource_database_id),
    OBJECT_NAME(resource_associated_entity_id, resource_database_id),
    COUNT(1) AS lock_count
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE resource_type = 'OBJECT'
GROUP BY request_session_id, request_owner_id, 
    resource_database_id, resource_associated_entity_id
```

When I run this query I am occasionally blocked by one of the sessions actually holding the locks.  If I remove `OBJECT_NAME` and `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME` then I don't have any problems.  I've tried dumping the information into a table and then using the functions on the values in the table with similar problems.

This leads me to believe the problem is in the `OBJECT_NAME` and `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME` functions but I'm not sure why or how to get around it.  I'm also not certain why I am sometimes blocked and sometimes not.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Because the metadata functions do not obey transaction isolation semantics. If you want to avoid getting blocked, join to `sys.schemas` and `sys.objects` instead of using the metadata functions. This will also allow you to set the isolation level in a single statement instead of peppering `NOLOCK` hints all over the query...

This was reported by Adam Machanic on Connect several versions ago:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=432497

Closed as Won't Fix.

Comment: Actually the NOLOCK hint was one of my attempts to fix that didn't work.  I missed it when I put the code into the question.  Unfortunately joining to sys.schemas and sys.objects only works if I'm pulling data for a single database.  The `OBJECT_*` functions have an additional `database_id` parameter that I can add.