# OBJECT_ID(...) function vs join on sys.tables and sys.schemas

Tags: sql-server, metadata, system-tables

When querying metadata for a specific table, I can either

1. use the [`OBJECT_ID` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or
2. join the relevant system tables (`sys.tables` and `sys.schemas`).

For example, both of those queries will return all DML triggers for table `myTable`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM sys.triggers AS t
 WHERE t.parent_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[myTable]', 'U')

SELECT *
  FROM sys.triggers AS tr
       INNER JOIN sys.tables AS tab ON tr.parent_id = tab.object_id 
       INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON tab.schema_id = s.schema_id 
 WHERE s.name = 'dbo' AND tab.name = 'myTable';
```

Is it purely a matter of taste, or is there a good reason to prefer one over the other (if both will solve your problem)?

My preliminary analysis is that:

- Option 1 is shorter (obviously).
- With Option 2 I don't need to worry about quoting/escaping the table/schema name (if it contains special characters).
- The query plans are different (but unlikely to make a huge difference, since this is not an operation I plan to do frequently).

Did I miss anything important?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converted from comments:

> The only thing you should really be aware of with `OBJECT_ID` is that it's database-context sensitive, and you may also need to supply that if you're querying across databases, eg from `master` to `any_user_database`. [Erik Darling](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32281/erik-darling)

> I remember an old Connect item (oh, found number 432497) complaining about `OBJECT_ID`. If I recall correctly, OBJECT_ID does not always respect transaction isolation level (also OBJECT_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, etc.). Querying *sys* were safe. It can make sense in DDL-triggers. [i-one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/99746/i-one)

> yeah, the metadata functions will block even if `read uncommitted` is specified rather than read another transaction's dirty data - [Martin Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3690/martin-smith)

> [Related](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56398/99746), [related](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204821/99746). - [i-one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/99746/i-one)

> I talk about the isolation level issue here: [Bad habits: Using (certain) metadata "helper" functions](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-metadata-helper-functions). - [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand)