# Problem with IF NOT EXISTS query in ms sql

Tags: sql-server, if-not-exists

I want to script query to validate if not have existing column test to add it after check condition. But in those two ways it is not working.

Way 1:

```
IF [dbo].[TEST].TEST NOT EXISTS
BEGIN
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TEST] ADD TEST INT;
```

Way 2:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TEST] ADD TEST INT
where NOT EXISTS in ([dbo].[TEST].TEST);
```

Comment: You want to check if the table exists or if any rows exist in the table?

Comment: @Charlieface I want to check if the row exist and if it's not exist to add it in the table.

Comment: You are adding a column not a row though?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, my mistake it's a column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to script conditional addition of a column (only if it does not already exist in the table), you can use the `sys.columns` system catalogue in this way:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    sys.columns
  WHERE
    object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TEST')
    AND name = 'TEST'
)
  ALTER TABLE
    dbo.TEST
  ADD
    TEST int NULL
;
```

Comment: `OBJECT_ID` has its own issues, eg https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56398/220697, maybe join `sys.tables`